# How to test if elements of an array are real or complex?

Tags: complex, list-manipulation

I am new to Mathematica and I have to select the elements in an array that only contain real numbers and eliminate the ones that  have complex parts. Basically the code that I have is an array of possible combinations of too variables c2l and c2h, so that they are the solution to a system of equations. The second part of my question is how to store just the real solutions in a new iobject. Thanks!

Comment: This can be achieved in a few different ways. Look up e.g. `Cases`, `DeleteCases`, and `Select` in the help files.

Comment: how do I use  Cases with an array though?

Comment: Try e.g. `Cases[yourarray, _Real]` to select only the real numbers; or alternatively `DeleteCases[yourarray, _Complex]` to remove the complex entries: the results should be the same if the array only contains numbers. These will work if you have a flat list of numbers; otherwise you might want to add a level specification or a more specific pattern. You will need to *show us a sample of your data* to get a better answer.

Comment: This is my array. It is composed by sets of solutions, so that the total length is 36 entries: `solsc2lc2hAll = Join[solsc2lc2h1, solsc2lc2h2, solsc2lc2h3, solsc2lc2h4, solsc2lc2h5]//DeleteDuplicates;`. A sample of the output it returns is: `solsc2lc2hAll [[1]]` returns `{c2l -> 1, c2h -> 1}`. Now, some of these c2h and c2kl are complex and I need to descard them, how can I make Mathematica read it?

Comment: Do you want to retain the `Rule` structure (i.e. `c2l -> 1`) or do you just want the values?

Comment: `Cases[r, ru : {Rule[_, _Real] ..} :> ru]` where *r* is your array to transform...

Comment: @Jmb It would be helpful for other members if you added the values of your variables (or a small samll sample) to the Question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the solutions to the following equation:

```
yoursolutions = {x, y} /. NSolve[{x^3 - y^3 == 2, x y == 3} , {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {{-0.923042 + 1.59876 I, -0.812531 - 1.40734 I}, 
>  {-0.923042 - 1.59876 I, -0.812531 + 1.40734 I}, 
>  {0.812531 + 1.40734 I, 0.923042 - 1.59876 I}, 
>  {0.812531 - 1.40734 I, 0.923042 + 1.59876 I}, 
>  {1.84608, 1.62506}, {-1.62506, -1.84608}}
> ```

Now let's use `Cases` to extract only the real solutions:

```
onlyrealsols = Cases[yoursolutions, {__Real}]
```

> ```
> {{1.84608, 1.62506}, {-1.62506, -1.84608}}
> ```

---

**UPDATE:** Here is a second version that **retains the `Rule` structure**:

```
solutionrules = NSolve[{x^3 - y^3 == 2, x y == 3} , {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {{x -> -0.923042 + 1.59876 I, y -> -0.812531 - 1.40734 I}, 
>  {x -> -0.923042 - 1.59876 I, y -> -0.812531 + 1.40734 I}, 
>  {x -> 0.812531 + 1.40734 I, y -> 0.923042 - 1.59876 I},
>  {x -> 0.812531 - 1.40734 I, y -> 0.923042 + 1.59876 I}, 
>  {x -> 1.84608,  y -> 1.62506}, {x -> -1.62506, y -> -1.84608}}
> ```

Again, we can use a modified pattern in `Cases` to select those rules corresponding to real solutions:

```
realsolutionrules = Cases[
    solutionrules,
    {_ -> solx_, _ -> soly_} /; {solx, soly} \[Element] Reals
  ]
```

> ```
> {{x -> 1.84608, y -> 1.62506}, {x -> -1.62506, y -> -1.84608}}
> ```

Comment: It is not working... I think my problem is that the elements in the array are associations, such as `{c2l -> 1, c2h -> 1}`. So when I have something like '{c2l -> 0.764706, c2h -> 0.764706 + 1.58207*10^-14 I}` it is not deleting when I use `DeleteCases[solsc2lc2hAll], _Complex]` it still comes up in the output

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: @Jmb It does. The question is, do you want to retain the `Rule` (->) structure, or do you just care about the values? If you care about the values, see how I extracted the values from the rules produced by `NSolve` in my example above.

Comment: I need to retain the `Rule` structure, because I need to plug in these solutions on another set of equations... How can I do this?

Comment: @Jmb OK take a look at the updated version of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Position` and `Extract` with `Repeated` for your pattern.

Starting with @MarcoB solutions.

```
sol = NSolve[{x^3 - y^3 == 2, x y == 3}, {x, y}]
(*
{{x -> -0.923042 + 1.59876 I, y -> -0.812531 - 1.40734 I}, 
 {x -> -0.923042 - 1.59876 I, y -> -0.812531 + 1.40734 I}, 
 {x -> 0.812531 + 1.40734 I, y -> 0.923042 - 1.59876 I}, 
 {x -> 0.812531 - 1.40734 I, y -> 0.923042 + 1.59876 I}, 
 {x -> 1.84608, y -> 1.62506}, 
 {x -> -1.62506, y -> -1.84608}}
*)
```

We are looking for a `Repeated` (`..`) pattern of a `Symbol` to `Real` `Rule`.  A pattern for this is `(_Symbol -> _Real)..`. The parenthesis group parts together so Mma knows which part to repeat.  You can also tell `Repeated` exactly how many times to repeat but one or more is fine for this case.

```
realPos = Position[sol, {(_Symbol -> _Real) ..}, 1]
(* {{5}, {6}} *)
```

The pattern in `Position` gives the locations in `sol` that match that pattern. This can also be done for `Complex` numbers.

```
complexPos = Position[sol, {(_Symbol -> _Complex) ..}, 1]
(* {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}} *)
```

`Extract` takes the list of positions and returns the elements in the list.

```
Extract[sol, realPos]
(* {{x -> 1.84608, y -> 1.62506}, {x -> -1.62506, y -> -1.84608}} *)

Extract[sol, complexPos]
(*
{{x -> -0.923042 + 1.59876 I, y -> -0.812531 - 1.40734 I}, 
 {x -> -0.923042 - 1.59876 I, y -> -0.812531 + 1.40734 I}, 
 {x -> 0.812531 + 1.40734 I, y -> 0.923042 - 1.59876 I}, 
 {x -> 0.812531 - 1.40734 I, y -> 0.923042 + 1.59876 I}}
*)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the simplest solution is adding the option `Reals` in `NSolve` directly. For instance,

```
NSolve[{x^3 - y^3 == 2, x y == 3}, {x, y}, Reals]
```

> ```
> {{x -> 1.84608, y -> 1.62506}, {x -> -1.62506, y -> -1.84608}}
> ```